# Understanding state in React

Tags: reactjs, state

I am creating an app which displays and hides UI elements on the page based on checkbox value of a 'toggler' and checkbox values of the list elements which are created from `this.state.items`.

The app has an initial state set as:

```
state = {
    items: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Water',
            isComplete: false
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Salt',
            isComplete: false
        }, {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Bread',
            isComplete: false
        }
    ],
    isChecked: false,
    currentItem: '',
    inputMessage: 'Add Items to Shopping Basket'
}
```

I created the following method which filters through `items` and returns all of the `isComplete: false`, and then I set the new state with these returned items.

```
toggleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({isChecked: !this.state.isChecked});
  if (!this.state.isChecked) {
    const filtered = this.state.items.filter(isComplete);
    this.setState({items: filtered})
  } else {
    // display previous state of this.state.items
  }
}
```

How do I come back to the 'Previous' state when I set 'toggler' to false?

Comment: Don't keep filtered list in state. Just filter dynamically in `render`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to keep the default list then keep it out of state entirely
and just keep the filtered list in the state.

This way you could always filter the original list.

You can even consider filtering in the render method itself and not keeping the filtered list in state at all.

If you need to go back before a change was made (keeping history)
you could maintain another filtered list in your state.

Comment: Yes, I placed it on render instead, that how I avoided state change, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to do but, if you implement componentWillUpdate() (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate) you get access to the next state and the current state.

-nextState will be what your state is going to be, and this.state is what it is now.

You could save this.state into another variable called this.oldState before it is updated, and then refer back to it.

Nonetheless, since state doesn't keep history of itself, you might consider approaching the problem differently.